When I try to access IIS as localhost, I get not found
I am running a web application on IIS 10.0 + ASP.NET + azureVM.
When I type the IP address assigned to the VM in the address bar, it works fine,
However, when I specify localhost and 127.0.0.1, I get a not found 404.
Naturally, the application server browser is used for access.
Do you know of any settings in the IIS configuration where the behavior changes depending on the request address?
1.when localhost and 127.0.0.1 are specified, the routing table is normal.
2.The phenomenon does not change when the virus software is turned on or off.
3.IIS itself is running as indicated by the "not found 404" message and the fact that it works when an IP address is specified.
(The phenomenon does not change even if bind is added or removed because IIS is able to display the 404 page on 127.0.0.1.)

You might have misconfigured site bindings, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/binding-diagnostics, or something in HTTP API Reserved URLs takes high priority, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/https-binding

It is impossible to analyze your problem based on these error messages alone. How do you configuring your website in iis? please post relevant information.

Thank you Lex Li
Your information was very useful!
This problem was caused by site binding.
My IIS configuration assumes two virtual directories.

the directory that is configured in the site advanced settings (empty)
added virtual directory (AP running)

When accessing with localhost and 127.0.0.1, it was bound to 1. 404 error because it was empty.
When using the IP address assigned to the VM, it was bound to 2 and the result was as expected.
I specified the virtual directory where the application runs as the directory for 1, and all request methods produced the expected results.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
